# Javascript: remember selected range of a text

Tags: selection, range, javascript, textrange

I am trying to find a way to remember/store a JScript textrange and then apply it back to a text and convert it into a selection.

An example: in an iframe which is in "designmode" and contains the text "This is text inside the frame", the user hilights/selects "is text".

I can read that selection by using all the available range methods. No problem so far.
Now clicking a button creates creates another iframe containing the same text as the first one and the first iframe gets removed. In that second iframe I want to select the same text the user selected in the first frame.
Now the problems start: the range object from iframe 1 cannot be used for iframe 2. Somehow the range object seems to be tied to its source element. Setting the range has either no effect or weird errors.
How can I re-select whatever WAS selected?

Comment: This extra iframe: are you copying the whole HTML from the original iframe to it?

Comment: Not copying it but we can assume that the content of the extra iframe is identical. So somehow I would have to know "the fith word was selected", or "the third image", or "the second word and the following paragraph and the following table" and then select the same things in the extra iframe.

Comment: my edit: added some tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. textRange provides many methods/properties, for example to determine the position.

So if you say, that's not a real copy, but identical, you can fetch the positions of frame1 and create upon them a new selection in frame2.

I was playing around with it a little bit, here's the result:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>title</title>

  <script type="text/jscript">

  function cloneSelection()
  {
    if(!document.all || window.opera)
    {
      alert('this is an jscript-example for MSIE5+');
      return;
    }
    var editors=window.frames;  
        editors[0].focus();

    //create 2 ranges in the first iframe 
    var r1=editors[0].document.selection.createRange();
    var r2=editors[0].document.selection.createRange();

    //checkout if a control is selected
    if(editors[0].document.selection.type==='Control')
    {    
      var obj=r1.item(0);
      var objs=editors[0].document.body.getElementsByTagName(obj.tagName);

      //iterate over the elements to get the index of the element
      for(var i=0;i<objs.length;++i)
      {
        if(objs[i]===obj)
        {
          //create a controlRange, add the found control and select it
          var controls=editors[1].document.body.createControlRange();
              controls.add(editors[1].document.body.getElementsByTagName(obj.tagName)[i]);
              controls.select()
          return;
        }
      }
      //control-branch done
    }

    //no control was selected, so we work with textRanges  
    //collapse the 2nd range created above 
    r2.collapse(false); 

    //store the positions of the 2 ranges
    var x1=r1.offsetLeft;
    var y1=r1.offsetTop;
    var x2=r2.offsetLeft;
    var y2=r2.offsetTop;

    //create ranges in the 2nd iframe and move them to the stored positions
    var r2=editors[1].document.body.createTextRange();
        r2.moveToPoint(x1,y1);
    var r3=editors[1].document.body.createTextRange();
        r3.moveToPoint(x2,y2);

    //set the move the end of the first range to start of the 2nd range
    r2.setEndPoint('EndToStart',r3);

    //select the first range
    r2.select(); 
  }


  //fill the iframes and make them editable
  window.onload=function()
  {
    var editors=window.frames;
    for(var i=0;i<frames.length;++i)
    {
      with(frames[i].document)
      {
        open();
        write('This is text is an image '+
              '<br/><img src="http://sstatic.net/ads/img/careers-ad-header-so.png"><br/>'+
              'this is inside this frame');
        designMode='On';
        close();
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
  iframe{width:400px;height:200px;}
  -->
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
      <input type="button" value="cloneSelection()" onclick="cloneSelection()">
      <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[test with jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/SPPjb/)**

Notice that this demo so far is build for MSIE only(you wrote you like to do it with JScript^^) .

But it should also be possible to implement it for other browsers.

Comment: That's marvelous! Makes me wonder how little I know about JScript! I'll check if that solves it for IE. If yes, I'll make it work for Firefox. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: But please explain: to select something in IE, you specify absolute coordinate in pixels and IE knows what to select from those coordinates? Why is it then necessary to treat objects separately? Isn't everything an object (a link, a textnode, a table, an image)?

Comment: Those objects (e.g. images, form-elements) represent another type of range in IE, "controlRange". This type of range has properties different from a textRange. This type of range for example does'nt have the properties of a textRange to  determine position or move start/end of the range. Those ranges represent more than  a textRange the DOM-Element-Object/s . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537447%28VS.85%29.aspx